# Possible to have different behavior for landscape orientation in launch screen storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

In my `Launch Screen.storyboard`, I have a `UIImageView` named `LaunchScreenIcon` that scales proportionally to the width of the screen by setting the `LaunchScreenIcon.width = width` constraint.

Is it somehow possible to change the behavior for landscape orientation so that the height of the `UIImageView` scales to the height of the screen i.e. `LaunchScreenIcon.height = height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by:

1. Going to my `Launch Screen.storyboard`
2. Selecting the large iPad model in landscape from the panel at the
   bottom
3. Tapping "Vary for Traits" to the right and checking off both width
   and height
4. Then I added the constraint as I normally would and it was now only
   associated with the large iPad model in landscape

Answer (score 0):

Constrain your image view to `0` on all four sides (so it fills the entire view), then set its `Content Mode` to `Aspect Fit`

That should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This actually might be better than my solution below if it can be done without adding a specific constraint to a device.